# How to fix the there is no attribute "tick" in my code when what everyone else is doing is pygame.time.Clock.tick()?

Tags: python, error-handling, pygame, attributeerror

Well , I was trying to make a game with pygame in python ( ver. 3.10.5 ) . I wanted to set Frames Per Seconds , that is FPS for the game by first doing clock = pygame.time.Clock outside the main loop and then doing clock.tick(FPS) , (FPS was another variable before with a value of 27). In every video in Youtube , it works , but in my one it shows "builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'tick' " . I searched a lot but can't find the proper fix or alternative. Please help

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((500 , 500))
pygame.display.set_caption("G")

walkRight = [pygame.image.load('R1.png'), pygame.image.load('R2.png'), pygame.image.load('R3.png'), pygame.image.load('R4.png'), pygame.image.load('R5.png'), pygame.image.load('R6.png'), pygame.image.load('R7.png'), pygame.image.load('R8.png'), pygame.image.load('R9.png')]
walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('L1.png'), pygame.image.load('L2.png'), pygame.image.load('L3.png'), pygame.image.load('L4.png'), pygame.image.load('L5.png'), pygame.image.load('L6.png'), pygame.image.load('L7.png'), pygame.image.load('L8.png'), pygame.image.load('L9.png')]
bg = pygame.image.load('bg.jpg')
char = pygame.image.load('standing.png')

clock = pygame.time.Clock

x = 50
y = 50
width = 64
height = 64
vel = 5

FPS = 27

jumping = False
jump_count = 10

left = False
right = False
walkCount = 0


def redrawGameWindow():
    global walkCount

    window.blit(bg , (0, 0))

    if walkCount + 1 >= 27:
        walkCount = 0

    if left:
        window.blit(walkLeft[walkCount//3] , (x,y))
    pygame.display.update()




running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if running == False:
            pygame.quit()

    neg = 1

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        x = x - vel
        left = True
        right = False
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        x = x + vel
        right = True
        left = False
    else:
        left = False
        right = False
        walkCount = 0
    if not (jumping):
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            y = y - vel
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            y = y + vel
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            jumping = True
    else:
        if jump_count >= -10:
            neg = 1
            if jump_count < 0:
                neg = -1
            y -= jump_count ** 2 * 0.5 * neg
            jump_count -= 1
        else:
            jumping = False
            jump_count = 10

    redrawGameWindow()
```

This is what I tried and i cant fix pls help it shows builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'tick'

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

`pygame.time.Clock` is a [`class`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html). You have to create an [instance object](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects) of that class:

<s>`clock = pygame.time.Clock`</s>

```py
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
```